# displaying pages containing wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I wrote a shortcode for wordpress to display wordpress posts and pages. Displaying posts is fine but when I try to display pages, it goes on infinitely. I guess one of the pages contains  the shortcode and hence it displays recursively. Can anyone suggest me the solution for this. As to how I can prevent short code from being executed while displaying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not totally sure if I understand correctly. Maybe you just need to have the shortcode run not from a page but in a template php file.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

otherwise you will need to exclude that page from being displayed in your shortcode manually, is it a plugin you are working with?

Comment: Recursion was not because of shortcode but some bug in my code which got solved. And if you want to display short code then we need to include it inside square bracket.